# In Azure AD B2C custom policies, how do the IdentityExperienceFrameworkApps connect to AD without secrets

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Also posted to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/issues/29

In the [B2C Custom Policy Starterpack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack) we have the file `LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml` with:

```
<TechnicalProfiles>
   <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="client_id">ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId</Item>
      <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppID" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppID" />
    </InputClaims>
  </TechnicalProfile>
</TechnicalProfiles>
```

Can someone explain why two applications are required to make these custom policies work?
How does the IEF use each of them?

Besides, I don't see any secret or application key being passed to IEF in these files. How can IEF connect to AAD using Application Ids only?

Answer (score 1):

[The **login-NonInteractive** technical profile](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/351aedd166aaa1f66695afa36cb45a6493336db3/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L394) authenticates a local account by sending an access token request, using the resource owner password credentials grant type, to your Azure AD directory:

```xml
<Metadata>
  <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token</Item>
</Metadata>
<InputClaims>
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="password" />
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppID" />
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppID" />
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="username" Required="true" />
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="openid" />
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="nca" PartnerClaimType="nca" DefaultValue="1" />
</InputClaims>
```

Like all access token requests for an Azure AD directory, this access request must contain the identifier of a client application (i.e. the **ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework** application) and that of a resource application (i.e. the **IdentityExperienceFramework** application).

You don't have to specify a secret for the client application because it is [registered as a native application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom#register-the-proxyidentityexperienceframework-application).

Comment: So, my understanding is that the native application, ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework, will authenticate against AD using the user's credentials as if it were any other native application that anyone else could have registered directly on their AD. Is that right? If, so, that should result in an authentication token being sent from AD back to the engine that is running the policy. If that's the case, is this what's stored in the B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer?

Comment: Moreover, in a subsequent step, I understand the AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId  Technical Profile (which extends AAD-Common) will be used to read the user's details from AD like its displayName, givenName, surname, etc. At that point, how does it interact with AD? Does it connect via Microsoft Graph? If so, how does it get an auth token for Graph? Would it be requesting one using the identity token it got from the previous login-NonInteractive?

Comment: The authentication token is validated by the IEF engine, claims that are contained in it are mapped by the `login-NonInteractive` TP, and then it is discarded.

Comment: The `B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer` key is used to sign the ID and access tokens that are issued by Azure AD B2C to your relying party applications.

Comment: In order to integrate with the B2C directory, the B2C engine is authenticating as itself (i.e. as an internal app called "CPIM Service") and then using the Azure AD Graph API to read and write the directory data.

Comment: Thanks for all these comments. Have you found any official documentation from MS that explains this? What the CPIM Service is, how it works, how it authenticates against AD, and that it uses the AD Graph API, etc.?

Comment: In addition, when you say "using the Azure AD Graph API to read and write the directory data", is that related or dependent on the permissions we need to grant to the ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework and to the IdentityExperienceFramework to read the Windows Azure Active Directory? (as stated in the documentation)

Comment: No, there isn't any official documentation that describes this, AFAIK. When the "CPIM Service" app is interacting with your directory data, it is doing so under its own identity, not one that is related to the "ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework" or "IdentityExperienceFramework" apps.